# A way to generate Vuex Getter Setter in VSCode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuex, generator, getter-setter

Is there a way to easily generate vuex Getter and Setter whithin computed property in VSCode (Visual Studio Code) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here a way to generate Vuex Getter and Setter within computed property.

I use VSCode Snippet. Here the snippet code :

```
{
"Vuex Getter and Setter ": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript,vue",
    "prefix": "gset",
    "body": [
        "${2:property}: {",
        "\tget() {",
        "\t\treturn this.\\$store.state.${1:objet}.${2:property}",
        "\t},",
        "\tset(value) {",
        "\t\tthis.\\$store.commit('update${1/^(.)(.*)/${1:/upcase}${2}/}${2/^(.)(.*)/${1:/upcase}${2}/}', value)",
        "\t}",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Generate vuex getter and setter for an object and a property"
}
```

}

Here the result :

[image: result]

If you know a better way, or cool VSCode plugin to do that, i would be happy to learn